# Html input type [Number]

Tags: html, forms

Can anyone suggest a php or javascript code that automatically fills the Html form which contains `input type= "number" step= "any"`, with value zero if the user tries to leave the form blank? Blank cells are regarded non-numeric and hence are throwing php warnings.

Comment: Use a default value. `<input type="number" value="0">`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use javascript for that.

```
$( "#myinput" ).focusout(function() {
   $( "#myinput" ).value(0);
});
```

Sorry for jQuery. It is the simples one you can use, I suppose. 
UPD: Default value should be set to 0, of course.

Comment: doesn't work if the user leaves the field empty without touching it

Comment: of course it should be used with the default value set to 0

Comment: I did set the value to zero and added the jquery code , it still throws a php warning saying you have entered a non number input. ofcourse i removed the zero that showed in form and entered submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="number" name="YourName" value='0' step="put_your_step_here">
```

You pre-set the value of your field to 0 so no matter if the user leaves it without touching it the value will be 0 by default so your problem is solved.

Comment: While it is a correct answer it is a good practice to add some text commenting how it works.